# how to customize snackBar's layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-snackbar, snackbar

Is there any method to change the layout of a snackBar to custom View?

Now it comes black and we can change the background color.
But I don't know the right way to inflate a new layout and making it as snackBars background?

Thanks...

Answer (score 164, accepted):

The Snackbar does not allow you to set a custom layout. However, as Primoz990 suggested you can get the Snackbar's View. The getView function returns the Snackbar.SnackbarLayout, which is a horizontal LinearLayout object whose children are a TextView and a Button. To add your own View to the Snackbar, you just need to hide the TextView, and add your View to the Snackbar.SnackbarLayout.

```java
// Create the Snackbar
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(containerLayout, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
// Get the Snackbar's layout view
Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
// Hide the text
TextView textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

// Inflate our custom view
View snackView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_snackbar, null);
// Configure the view
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) snackView.findViewById(R.id.image);
imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
TextView textViewTop = (TextView) snackView.findViewById(R.id.text);
textViewTop.setText(text);
textViewTop.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

//If the view is not covering the whole snackbar layout, add this line
layout.setPadding(0,0,0,0);

// Add the view to the Snackbar's layout
layout.addView(snackView, 0);
// Show the Snackbar
snackbar.show();
```

Comment: hi..this works for me...but my snackbar's width is not fully stretched

Comment: I'd warn caution with this sort of thing. You never know if and when the internal implementation details of these system classes will change. If it doesn't do what you need then it is safer to implement a custom component of your own that does.

Comment: I'll advice you use crouton library

Comment: @Ozuf well Crouton library is deprecated

Comment: @JJD In my case it opens on full activity,why this happens?

Comment: Starting at v 25.1.0 this become possible. Please check my post below. Thanks for nice answer!

Comment: Extend `BaseTransientBottomBar` instead, per https://stackoverflow.com/a/41154330/9636

Comment: I made a repository based on Mike's answer:
https://github.com/LucasFebatis/customsnackbar

Comment: (android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text)  results in: Cannot resolve symbol 'design' in API 30

Comment: If you're using material the new ID is com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text

Comment: and also cast to MaterialTextView instead of TextView

Answer (score 73):

It is possible starting from [25.1.0 revision of Android Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/rev-archive#25-1-0)

[image]

I. Declare custom layout in your values/layout folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/snackbar_action"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/design_snackbar_extra_spacing_horizontal"              
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/design_snackbar_extra_spacing_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right|end"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/design_snackbar_padding_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/design_snackbar_padding_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/design_snackbar_padding_horizontal"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/design_snackbar_padding_horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
    style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

<TextView
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:id="@+id/snackbar_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/design_snackbar_padding_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/design_snackbar_padding_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/design_snackbar_padding_horizontal"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/design_snackbar_padding_horizontal"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Design.Snackbar.Message"
    android:maxLines="@integer/design_snackbar_text_max_lines"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left|start"
    android:ellipsize="end"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

*Hints:*

- *Use `@dimen/design_snackbar` values to match material design guidelines.*
- *Use `?attr/colorAccent` to apply your Application Theme changes to Snackbar.*

II. Extend [BaseTransientBottomBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BaseTransientBottomBar.html) class.

```
public class final CustomSnackbar extends BaseTransientBottomBar<CustomSnackbar> {

/**
 * Constructor for the transient bottom bar.
 *
 * @param parent The parent for this transient bottom bar.
 * @param content The content view for this transient bottom bar.
 * @param contentViewCallback The content view callback for this transient bottom bar.
 */
private CustomSnackbar(ViewGroup parent, View content,    
            ContentViewCallback contentViewCallback) {
    super(parent, content, contentViewCallback);
}
}
```

III. Add [BaseTransientBottomBar.ContentViewCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BaseTransientBottomBar.ContentViewCallback.html)

```
public class final CustomSnackbar ...{

...

private static class ContentViewCallback implements        
                   BaseTransientBottomBar.ContentViewCallback {

  // view inflated from custom layout
  private View content;

  public ContentViewCallback(View content) {
      this.content = content;
  }

  @Override
  public void animateContentIn(int delay, int duration) {
      // add custom *in animations for your views
      // e.g. original snackbar uses alpha animation, from 0 to 1
      ViewCompat.setScaleY(content, 0f);
      ViewCompat.animate(content)
                .scaleY(1f).setDuration(duration)
                .setStartDelay(delay);
  }

  @Override
  public void animateContentOut(int delay, int duration) {
      // add custom *out animations for your views
      // e.g. original snackbar uses alpha animation, from 1 to 0
      ViewCompat.setScaleY(content, 1f);
      ViewCompat.animate(content)
                .scaleY(0f)
                .setDuration(duration)
                .setStartDelay(delay);
  }
}
}
```

IV. Add method to create Snackbar with custom layout and methods to fill it.

```
public class final CustomSnackbar ...{

...

public static CustomSnackbar make(ViewGroup parent, @Duration int duration) {
 // inflate custom layout
 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
 View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.snackbar_view, parent, false);

 // create snackbar with custom view
 ContentViewCallback callback= new ContentViewCallback(content);
 CustomSnackbar customSnackbar = new CustomSnackbar(parent, content, callback);
// Remove black background padding on left and right
customSnackbar.getView().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);


 // set snackbar duration
 customSnackbar.setDuration(duration);
 return customSnackbar;
 }

 // set text in custom layout
 public CustomSnackbar setText(CharSequence text) {
 TextView textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.snackbar_text);
 textView.setText(text);
 return this;
 }

 // set action in custom layout
 public CustomSnackbar setAction(CharSequence text, final OnClickListener  listener) {
 Button actionView = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.snackbar_action);
 actionView.setText(text);
 actionView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 actionView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         listener.onClick(view);
         // Now dismiss the Snackbar
         dismiss();
     }
 });
 return this;
}
}
```

V. Create instance of `CustomSnackbar` and call `show()` method.

```
CustomSnackbar customSnackbar = CustomSnackbar.make(rooView,      CustomSnackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
customSnackbar.setText("No network connection!");
customSnackbar.setAction("Retry", new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // handle click here
    }
});
customSnackbar.show();
```

See more about Snackbar and its customization at [materialdoc.com](http://www.materialdoc.com/snackbar/)

Full `CustomSnackbar.class` code :

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BaseTransientBottomBar;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class CustomSnackbar extends BaseTransientBottomBar<CustomSnackbar> {

    /**
     * Constructor for the transient bottom bar.
     *
     * @param parent The parent for this transient bottom bar.
     * @param content The content view for this transient bottom bar.
     * @param callback The content view callback for this transient bottom bar.
     */
    private CustomSnackbar(ViewGroup parent, View content, ContentViewCallback callback) {
        super(parent, content, callback);
    }

    public static CustomSnackbar make(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, @Duration int duration) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        final View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.snackbar_view, parent, false);
        final ContentViewCallback viewCallback = new ContentViewCallback(content);
        final CustomSnackbar customSnackbar = new CustomSnackbar(parent, content, viewCallback);

        customSnackbar.getView().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        customSnackbar.setDuration(duration);
        return customSnackbar;
    }

    public CustomSnackbar setText(CharSequence text) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setText(text);
        return this;
    }

    public CustomSnackbar setAction(CharSequence text, final View.OnClickListener listener) {
        Button actionView = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.snackbar_action);
        actionView.setText(text);
        actionView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        actionView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listener.onClick(view);
                // Now dismiss the Snackbar
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        return this;
    }

    private static class ContentViewCallback implements BaseTransientBottomBar.ContentViewCallback {

        private View content;

        public ContentViewCallback(View content) {
            this.content = content;
        }

        @Override
        public void animateContentIn(int delay, int duration) {
            ViewCompat.setScaleY(content, 0f);
            ViewCompat.animate(content).scaleY(1f).setDuration(duration).setStartDelay(delay);
        }

        @Override
        public void animateContentOut(int delay, int duration) {
            ViewCompat.setScaleY(content, 1f);
            ViewCompat.animate(content).scaleY(0f).setDuration(duration).setStartDelay(delay);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AmirZiarati yes, and its components are swapped (by default action button is on the right side).

Comment: I am getting margins on the left and right so black background is visible. How to remove it?

Comment: @AmirZiarati to make it show from the bottom, you need to copy a private static method from the Snackbar class. I've highlighted the method in an answer to the question.

Comment: how do I set transparent background?

Comment: @YakivMospan for me it's showing from bottom, can you please tell me how can I show it from top ?

Comment: To show snackbar show on bottom use snackbar.getView().setY() to set its position on parent.getHeight() - view.getHeight() - margin if you want. Remember to do it in OnGlobalLayoutListener to have actual values for heights.

Comment: Note that custom Snackbar might not be visible on screen if it has incorrect parent, original Snackbar resolves parent via findSuitableParent() function, so it should also be copied for getting correct parent from the one provided into the make() function.

Answer (score 25):

## The XML way:

The original layout xml file that is used for the `Snackbar` is this file:

### **`design_layout_snackbar_include.xml`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>        
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/snackbar_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
              ...
            android:ellipsize="end"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/snackbar_action"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
              ...
            android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
            style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

</merge>
```

So in order to **override this layout** you should write your own layout with the same `android:id`s as in this one and in your **`refs.xml`** file you should add this line:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
   ....   
    <item name="design_layout_snackbar_include" tools:override="true" type="layout">
        @layout/my_layout_snackbar
    </item>
   ....
</resources>
```

Comment: This worked well for me previously but after updating to Design Support Library 25.1.0 I started to get a merge layout exception. I found [this code](https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-design/blob/a881a1f86c3aa15d1df489b521a6c73b67b3f397/res/layout/design_layout_snackbar_include.xml) that made me change the merge tag into a view and it works again now.

Comment: this doesn't stretch the width. damn this android !!!!
why changing a view must be a pain. damn it !!

Comment: Material docs say to extend `BaseTransientBottomBar`, per https://stackoverflow.com/a/41154330/9636

Answer (score 24):

[image: Image for code written]

```
private Snackbar showSnackbar(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, int duration) { // Create the Snackbar
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "", duration);
    // 15 is margin from all the sides for snackbar
    int marginFromSides = 15;

    float height = 100;

    //inflate view
    View snackView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.snackbar_layout, null);

    // White background
    snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    // for rounded edges
    snackbar.getView().setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_edges));

    Snackbar.SnackbarLayout snackBarView = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams parentParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) snackBarView.getLayoutParams();
    parentParams.setMargins(marginFromSides, 0, marginFromSides, marginFromSides);
    parentParams.height = (int) height;
    parentParams.width = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    snackBarView.setLayoutParams(parentParams);

    snackBarView.addView(snackView, 0);
    return snackbar;
}
```

In onCreate of the Activity:

```
CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);

final Snackbar snackbar = showSnackbar(coordinatorLayout, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snackbar.show();
            View view = snackbar.getView();
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.snackbar_action);
            tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    snackbar.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 23):

The answer is: Don't customize the Snackbar. It should not contain any more elements than a short text and one action. See [Google Material design guidelines](https://material.io/archive/guidelines/components/snackbars-toasts.html).

UPDATE:
If you anyway want to customize the Snackbar here is what I have implemented in my app:

```java
//generate the snackbar
Snackbar sb = Snackbar.make(rootView, snack.text, duration);
//set te action button text color
sb.setActionTextColor(mCurrentActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.snack_text_action));
//Get the view of the snackbar
View sbView = sb.getView();
//set background color
sbView.setBackgroundColor(mCurrentActivity.getResources().getColor(backgroudResId));
//Get the textview of the snackbar text
TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
//set text color
textView.setTextColor(mCurrentActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.snack_text));
//increase max lines of text in snackbar. default is 2.
textView.setMaxLines(10);
```

I have never tried, but with getting the the root view of the Snackbar, you could programmatically add new views to the Snackbar.

Comment: As you could see yourself while developing a software, material guidelines do not always consider all use-cases, not to mention all the design inconsistencies that their design team deliberately chose to ignore.

Answer (score 18):

I tried it and it works!

```
View custom = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);
snackbar.getView().setPadding(0,0,0,0);
((ViewGroup) snackbar.getView()).removeAllViews();
((ViewGroup) snackbar.getView()).addView(custom);
TextView textView = custom.findViewById(R.id.text);
View button = custom.findViewById(R.id.button);
textView.setText("Your text here");
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is my util classcode for kotlin:
https://gist.github.com/Ryszardenko/db429bc7d177e646ffe27e0672a0958c#file-customsnackbar-kt

```
class CustomSnackbar(private val view: View) {

    fun showSnackBar(title: String, cancelFun: () -> Unit = {}) {
        val snackView = View.inflate(view.context, R.layout.snackbar, null)
        val binding = SnackbarBinding.bind(snackView)
        val snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        (snackbar.view as ViewGroup).removeAllViews()
        (snackbar.view as ViewGroup).addView(binding.root)
        snackbar.view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
        snackbar.view.elevation = 0f
        snackbar.setBackgroundTint(
            ContextCompat.getColor(
                view.context,
                android.R.color.transparent
            )
        )
        binding.tvTitle.text = title
        binding.btnCancel.setOnClickListener {
            cancelFun()
            snackbar.dismiss()
        }
        snackbar.show()
    }
}
```

cancelFun() is a lambda, by default empty - you can pass there for example "undo" function.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code.

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(container, "No Internet Connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
View sbView = snackbar.getView();
sbView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
snackbar.show();
```

**Note:**

> **container** - parent view of layout.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Yakiv Mospan's answer, to make your custom `BaseTransientBottomBar` show from the bottom like a `Snackbar`, copy this method from the `Snackbar` class to find a suitable parent in for the `BaseTransientBottomBar` constructor.

```
private static ViewGroup findSuitableParent(View view) {
    ViewGroup fallback = null;
    do {
        if (view instanceof CoordinatorLayout) {
            // We've found a CoordinatorLayout, use it
            return (ViewGroup) view;
        } else if (view instanceof FrameLayout) {
            if (view.getId() == android.R.id.content) {
                // If we've hit the decor content view, then we didn't find a CoL in the
                // hierarchy, so use it.
                return (ViewGroup) view;
            } else {
                // It's not the content view but we'll use it as our fallback
                fallback = (ViewGroup) view;
            }
        }

        if (view != null) {
            // Else, we will loop and crawl up the view hierarchy and try to find a parent
            final ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
            view = parent instanceof View ? (View) parent : null;
        }
    } while (view != null);

    // If we reach here then we didn't find a CoL or a suitable content view so we'll fallback
    return fallback;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**My personal utils + Time saving way to customize Snackbar and show it in your Activity or fragment**

```
    fun showSnackbar(view: View, context: Context, text: String) {
    val snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)

    val snackbarLayout = snackbar.view as Snackbar.SnackbarLayout
    snackbarLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    snackbarLayout.elevation = 0F
    snackbarLayout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)

    val snackContentLayout = snackbarLayout.getChildAt(0) as SnackbarContentLayout
    snackContentLayout.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.bg_main_corner)
    snackContentLayout.elevation = 5F
    snackContentLayout.setPadding(30, 0, 30, 0)

    val tvSnackbarTextView = snackContentLayout.getChildAt(0) as AppCompatTextView
    tvSnackbarTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
    tvSnackbarTextView.typeface = Typeface.SANS_SERIF
    tvSnackbarTextView.textSize = 14F

    val btnSnackbarActionButton = snackContentLayout.getChildAt(1) as AppCompatButton
    btnSnackbarActionButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8BC34A"))
    btnSnackbarActionButton.typeface = Typeface.SANS_SERIF
    btnSnackbarActionButton.textSize = 12F

    snackbar.setAction(R.string.rate_it) { rateApp(context) }

    snackbar.show()
}
```

***Just call it in your Activity or fragment***

```
 showSnackbar(findViewById(android.R.id.content),this@ScratchActivity, "Already Credit to your wallet!!!")
```

***Thank You***

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin Version for the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33441214/2437655

```
 private fun showSnackbar() {
        val snackbar = Snackbar.make(
                binding.root,
                "",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
        )
        (snackbar.view as Snackbar.SnackbarLayout).apply {
            findViewById<View>(R.id.snackbar_text).visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            findViewById<View>(R.id.snackbar_action).visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            val snackbarBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<SnackbarBinding>(
                    LayoutInflater.from(this@SnackbarActivity),
                    R.layout.snackbar,
                    binding.root as ViewGroup,
                    false
            )
            setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
            addView(snackbarBinding.root, 0)
        }
        snackbar.setDuration(8000).show()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library. This is a wrapper for android default snackbar.
https://github.com/ChathuraHettiarachchi/CSnackBar

```
Snackbar.with(this,null)
    .type(Type.SUCCESS)
    .message("Profile updated successfully!")
    .duration(Duration.SHORT)
    .show();
```

or you can even use your own view,

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);

Snackbar.with(this,null)
        .type(Type.UPDATE)
        .contentView(view, 76)
        .duration(Duration.SHORT)
        .show();
```

Currently only issue with custom layout is, we need to pass view height in dp as an input

Comment: Is it possible to have custom full width snackbar on any device using your library?

Comment: @yuralife Currently this is a wrapper for android snackbar, so cannot. only on mobile phone this will get whole width, on tablets this will not fill width