# What type of notification is this?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, intentservice

[This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anydo&hl=en) is a task manager. It provides notifications for tasks set by the user and on top of that provides information about missed calls. The format for the notification is exactly the same for any case, but I am unable to understand what type of a notification or rather 'what' it is. Could someone kindly help me out. Screenshot is below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a snack bar to me.which you can look for it's information from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html). and a tutorial from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-snackbar-example/)

but also you need to customize it to have a view like this for that you can follow this information [Customizing SnackBar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33441214/1744873)

Cheers!