# Opening layout on Floating action button click

Tags: android, android-layout

I want that when an item is added to cart the flaoting action button show open this layout. Does anyone have an idea how to do this..

This is the floating action button at the bottom right corner

[image: aa]

This is how the layout must open on fab click

[image: aa]

Please help me do this..

Comment: Use Snackbar http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html

Comment: You can show it as custom dialog on main layout

Comment: display custom dialog or change visibility of layout with circular animation.

Comment: ya i can use a custom dialog but it is a seperate activity and it causes the bacground layout to dim. I want it over the same layout such that elements on the parent layout are accessible when this dialog shows up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 options,

**Option 1**

On clicking fab just hide it and show a custom dialog box to the exact same position you want.

**Option 2**

Use a custom SnackBar and display it , example link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453946/how-to-customize-snackbars-layout)

**Option 3**

Use this library [FABRevealLayout](https://github.com/truizlop/FABRevealLayout) to expand FAB to a layout.