# Align Snackbar's Action on the right

Tags: android, android-snackbar, snackbar

Good afternoon,

I am working with Snackbars and I try to put an aciton (like UNDO), but the text is not aligned to the right of the screen.

The result I need :

[image]

The result I have :

[image]

As you can see, the "UNDO" action is not aligned right, as I need.

Here is my Snackbar code :

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(mMainContent, "Message deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            //Todo: Click on "UNDO"
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                            }
                        });

                snackbar.setActionTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.white));

                View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
                snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorAccent));
                snackbar.show();
```

Can someone help me ?

Thank you !

Comment: you have to prefer this default because in `Documentation` there is no method.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own custom snackbar layout [Custom snackbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453946/how-to-customize-snackbars-layout)

The core part is below

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->

// Create the Snackbar
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(containerLayout, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
// Get the Snackbar's layout view
Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
// Hide the text
TextView textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

// Inflate our custom view
View snackView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_snackbar, null);
// Configure the view
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) snackView.findViewById(R.id.image);
imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
TextView textViewTop = (TextView) snackView.findViewById(R.id.text);
textViewTop.setText(text);
textViewTop.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

// Add the view to the Snackbar's layout
layout.addView(snackView, 0);
// Show the Snackbar
snackbar.show();
```