# Moving navigation drawer items to right

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, right-to-left

I need your help please help me.
I have a navigation drawer in my app. i want to move navigation drawer to right completely . I moved the navigation itself but i want to move menu items to right too.

[My Screenshot of Navigation Drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0QUJ.png)

***Activity_main:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginleft="100dip"                                   
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="end">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My items of menu in xml :

***Activity_Main_Drawer:***

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/nav_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_photos"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_photo_library_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/nav_photos" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_movies"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_movies_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/nav_movies" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_notifications"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/nav_notifications" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/nav_settings" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Other">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_about_us"
                android:title="@string/nav_about_us" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_privacy_policy"
                android:title="@string/privacy_policy" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

**first:** You can put your device in RTL mode, go to develop settings (Force RTL layout direction).
After doing this  all the layouts will mirror correctly.
If you don't want to change the whole device into RTL use this code in onCreate method of mainactivity before super and before you inflate the content view

```
window.decorView.layoutDirection = View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for contributing with an answer but can you also add an explanation of what the attributes do and/or how they solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom layout for NavigationView.

According to this: http://www.kamilslesinski.com/home/navigation-drawer-customising-navigationview-items you can override the layout by copying original file and customizing it, or you can add a reference to your custom layout, like that:
[how to customize snackBar's layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453946/how-to-customize-snackbars-layout)
in refs.xml.