# Change the height of a snackbar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, snackbar

I can't access the width of the material-ui snackbar. When I use bodyStyle property and change height the app is updated accordingly. But why is width not changing?

Comment: You can do it through custom layout..
[here] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/33441214/5456671)

Comment: thank you, but the example is for android. I am using it in web application in react.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `bodyStyle` attribute with `maxWidth` and `height`, e.g.:

```
<Snackbar bodyStyle={{ maxWidth: '100%', height: 'auto' }} ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the bodyStyle property, and set flexGrow to zero (material-ui has it set to 1 which is overriding the width):

```
<Snackbar message="BIG snack" bodyStyle={{ height: 200, width: 200, flexGrow: 0 }} open />
```