# Is it possible to add some buttons or other different View's to Snackbar?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

If it posible could you tell me how can I do it? Else, please, tell me what can be used instead of Snackbar?

Comment: I strongly recommend to make a quick Google search before posting your question here dude, but well.. Looking at Google's official doc, you can add actions to the Snackbar https://developer.android.com/training/snackbar/action.html

Comment: For adding layouts to your Snackbar, this post may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33441214/4450805

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this. BUT, I don't recommend to use this workaround. Usually you don't need to put custom layout in snackbar. Snackbar was developed as a unified way for all apps to notify about something.

```
 CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_content);//coordimator layout where you use snackbar
            snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
            Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();//get the snackbar's view
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View snackView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
            snackView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            layout.addView(snackView, 0);//add our custom view to snackbar
            snackbar.show();
```

[example custom snackbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze66N.jpg)

Comment: How to do it through xml?

Comment: I dont know xml method. But you can create you xml custom view and add this view by inflater. I showed this method above