# Snackbar height is too large in pre-lollipop devices

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, android-snackbar

**WHAT I HAVE**

I am using Snackbar from the Design Support library in my app. I used to target API level 23 in my app, but have started noticing a weird problem after I started targeting API level 24.

**THE PROBLEM**

The problem only occurs for pre-lollipop devices, like Kitkat and Jellybean. It is perfectly fine for Lollipop and above devices. The height of the SnackBar is way too large compared to its standard size (please check the screenshot below).

When I using Design Support library and targeting API 23

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

everything was working fine. But when I started targeting API 24 and using,

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
```

the problem started occurring.

Is anyone else having the same issue? Is there something wrong I may be doing? How can it be fixed without decreasing the target SDK?

[image]

Comment: Didn't face this problem myself, but this may be an alternative : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33441214/3507492

Comment: I will look into the alternative. So are you targeting API 24 and using the Design Support Library 24.2.1 and not seeing this issue in Kitkat devices?

Comment: Targeting API 25 with Design Support Library 25.1.1, facing no such issue.

Comment: Did you try and check in the Android Studio emulator on version 4.4? I don't currently have a real device on Kitkat, so had to check on the emulator. Can it be an emulator specific bug?

Comment: did you managed to fix this?

Comment: any solution yet?

Comment: It happens on post-Lollipop too with supportLibVersion = '26.1.0'

Answer (score 2):

This can be fixed by

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(getRoot(), text, duration);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    snackbar.getView().setFitsSystemWindows(false);
}
snackbar.show();
```