# Smooth animateLayoutChanges animation

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to slid a view from the bottom of the screen and collapse another view a little everything will fit correctly.

I have managed to do that with the attribute `animateLayoutChanges` and 2 simple xml animations `slid_up.xml` and `slid_down.xml`.

My problem is that the animation that happens to `ViewPager` from the attribute `animateLayoutChanges` isn't smooth.

Is there a way to fix that?

**slid_up.xml**

```
<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0" />
 </set>
```

**slid_down.xml**

```
<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="100%" />
 </set>
```

**P.S.** I have tried to create custom animators as Height animators but it messes with the original height of the view.

**HeightResizeAnimation**

```
public class HeightResizeAnimation extends Animation {
    private View mView;
    private float mToHeight;
    private float mFromHeight;
    private int duration = 300;

    public HeightResizeAnimation(View v, float offset) {
        mView = v;
        mToHeight = v.getHeight() + offset;
        mFromHeight = v.getHeight();
        setDuration(duration);
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        float newHeight = (mToHeight - mFromHeight) * interpolatedTime + mFromHeight;
        mView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) newHeight;
        mView.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

after the animation the height will no longer be as `match_parent` that was before the animation.

**Update** 
Here is the animation that happens now
[image]

You can see that the fab animation to bottom isn't smooth also for the viewpager that the fab is child

Comment: Can you post the video of what you want to animate and we will update accordingly. No need for requestLayout() if using animation attributes.

Comment: the requestLayout isn't exactly a problem, the problem with the HeightResizeAnimation was if I change the view from portrait to landscape  the height will no longer be match_parent that was before the Animation

Comment: @AnuragSingh I have added and a video and a gif that is showing the animation that I like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the solution was to use the `android:clipChildren="false"`

As can be seen on the gif, the FAB is getting cropped while it is going down to the original position. So after I have used the `android:clipChildren="false"` on the parent of the FAB `viewPager` then the FAB isn't getting cropped anymore.

Comment: Please post the whole code, showing where you have used android:clipChildren="false"

Comment: it will not be easy to read if I put all the xml's of the layout.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you just want to show a snackbar + move the FAB along with it as it shows?
To do so you could use a combination of Snackbar and CoordinatorLayout from the Android Support Library: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-snackbar-example/

Comment: so the `Liked!` is a snackbar, so it is something like toast. Thanks a lot for your answer but it isn't what I want.

Comment: Hi @gmetax, looking at the updated animation I'd still say it should be a snackbar but with a custom view inside (https://material.io/guidelines/components/snackbars-toasts.html#) You can check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453946/how-to-customize-snackbars-layout Using a snackbar would probably help you with the smoothness of your animation as it is shown on top of the other views and it does not change the height of the views below.

Comment: but the snackbar is time limited. :/

Comment: after all the solution was to use the `android:clipChildren="false"`

Comment: @gmetax glad you found your solution :) FYI Snackbar does not have to be time limited - see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html#LENGTH_INDEFINITE

Comment: you are right, thanks for your help I have upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your xml layout add the following in the View:

```
android:visibility="gone"
android:alpha="0"
android:id="@+id/text_view_liked"
```

I am asumming the view to be `TextView`.
On the click of `ImageView` liked animate the `text_view_liked` with the following:

```
    final TextView textViewLiked = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_get_liked);
    final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    PropertyValuesHolder pvhYTextViewLiked = PropertyValuesHolder
        .ofFloat(View.Y,
            textViewLiked.getBottom(),
            (textViewLiked.getBottom() - textViewLiked.getHeight()));

    PropertyValuesHolder pvhAlphaTextViewLiked = PropertyValuesHolder
        .ofFloat(View.ALPHA, 0f, 1f);

    ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(textViewLiked,
        pvhYTextViewLiked,
        pvhAlphaTextViewLiked);

    ObjectAnimator objectAnimatorFab = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.Y, fab.getY(),
        fab.getY() - textViewLiked.getHeight());

    AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
    animatorSet.play(objectAnimator).with(objectAnimatorFab);
    animatorSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

      @Override
      public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        super.onAnimationStart(animation);
        textViewLiked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {

            PropertyValuesHolder pvhYTextViewLiked = PropertyValuesHolder
                .ofFloat(View.Y,
                    textViewLiked.getTop(),
                    (textViewLiked.getTop() + textViewLiked.getHeight()));

            PropertyValuesHolder pvhAlphaTextViewLiked = PropertyValuesHolder
                .ofFloat(View.ALPHA, 1f, 0f);

            ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(textViewLiked,
                pvhYTextViewLiked,
                pvhAlphaTextViewLiked);

            ObjectAnimator objectAnimatorFab = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.Y, fab.getY(),
                fab.getY() + textViewLiked.getHeight());

            AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
            animatorSet.play(objectAnimator).with(objectAnimatorFab);
            animatorSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
              @Override
              public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                textViewLiked.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              }
            });
            animatorSet.start();
          }
        }, 1000);

      }
    });
```

**You can adjust the duration accordingly**

`new Handler` is created just to automate the process of progress indicator is finished. You can just call on the finish of progress indicator.

Comment: You haven't understand the question. I don't want to create exactly like the `Liked!` but that is showing in the video. If I wanted to create the `Liked!` I would go with @Piotr Zawadzki answer. But tried your answer to check if the fab will have a smoother animation but it didn't had.

Comment: Snackbar has a limited time duration. You want to show progress indicator, inside that. My View can be view group. But Snackbar cann't. Also Snacbar width dosen't covers the whole screen width in tablet. Also, do let me know what I am missing. Do you want to move fab up and down as the view slides up and down with smooth transition?

Comment: your example was based on the `Liked!` view. I know the limitations of snackbar and I know I cannot use it as I want. If you see the gif on my question you will see that the fab isn't moving down smoothly and the viewpager(white background) also isn't moving smoothly

Comment: Updated the answer with fab. Adjust accordingly and do let me know

Comment: after all the solution was to use the `android:clipChildren="false"`

Comment: Glad to know. I have used in my XML. But it is for scaling beyond bounds. Thank-you

Comment: It's been grate :-)