# Why View.Gone not working in Snackbar?

Tags: android, android-snackbar, snackbar

I have a snackbar in which i want to remove textview but when i am using View.INVISIBLE then it is not showing uo but when using View.GONE then app is crashing by saying NullPointerException. Why so?

Here is the code

MainActivity.java

```
Snackbar sk=Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.ll),"It is checked",Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
sk.setAction("Undo",m);
sk.setActionTextColor(Color.GREEN);       

Snackbar.SnackbarLayout sl = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) sk.getView();

TextView t=sl.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
t.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Logcat

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: com.example.ankit.testing, PID: 29950
>                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.text.Layout.getLineCount()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                      at android.support.design.internal.SnackbarContentLayout.onMeasure(SnackbarContentLayout.java:85)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18820)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5961)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout.onMeasure(Snackbar.java:335)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18820)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5961)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18820)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5961)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18820)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5961)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18820)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5961)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18820)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5961)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2680)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18820)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2132)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1248)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1484)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6091)
>                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
>                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
>                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
>                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5437)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453946/how-to-customize-snackbars-layout/41154330

Answer (score 0):

**try this first create the Snackbar like this**

```
 // Create the Snackbar
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(containerLayout, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
```

**Get the Snackbar's layout view**

```
 Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
```

**Hide the text of snackbar like this**

```
 TextView textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

**set text to snackbar like this**

```
TextView textViewTop = (TextView)    
snackView.findViewById(R.id.text);
textViewTop.setText(text);
```

**Add the view to the Snackbar's layout**

```
layout.addView(snackView, 0);
```

**Show the Snackbar**

```
snackbar.show();
```

Comment: thanx.....but i do not want to add another laout .I just want to remove the text via View.GONE. Why is it not working. Thats my issue