# How to show downloading progress in a snackbar?

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar, android-download-manager, android-snackbar

I have an application which downloads PDFs from a WebView. I wanted to show the downloading progress in a snackbar and show "open" when downloaded which opens in Action_View.

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453946/how-to-customize-snackbars-layout

Comment: @Mr.AF I dint get my answer in that