# How to extend Snackbar in android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-snackbar

I want to create a class which extends Snackbar but I couldn't find the constructor in the Google documentation. How should I add the constructor to the class:

```
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar

class MySnackbar : Snackbar { 
    // Error: need a constructor
}
```

Comment: What do you want to add or change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SnackBar is final class and thus cannot be inherited. One way is to access SnackBar's view (`snackbar.getView()`) and modify the view as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

Snakbar is a final class and its not inherited but you can modify the view of snackbar.

Answer (score -1):

You can create secondary constructor, Use below code for Kotlin.

```
class MyCustomSeekBar : AppCompatSeekBar {
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I need it for Snakbar not Seekbar. These constructors works for Seekbar, TextView, EditText, ... but not Snakbar.

Comment: Please check this URL for customizing snack bar UI. [ https://stackoverflow.com/a/33441214/12688463 ]

Comment: @PatibandhaParth Check Question carefully , he want to extend the Snackbar class not modify the view of it