# Android - How to make a pop up message notification like this?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, toast, snackbar

[image]The pop up message is the Green one. I tried to use snackbar but many says Snackbar cant make custom layout and Toast doesnt have an action. So what should I use to make that green pop up message?

Comment: @Swayangjit ive read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453946/how-to-customize-snackbars-layout#:~:text=To%20add%20your%20own%20View,SnackbarLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom layout for Snackbar. Check-out the solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33441214/8122085

Comment: Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView(); how to do it in kotlin?

Comment: val layout = snackbar.view as Snackbar.SnackbarLayout